# How do you develop Android apps with Bluetooth?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, bluetooth, android-virtual-device

How do you effectively develop, debug, and test an android app that is based on Bluetooth.

I have been googling and searing stack overflow for the answer to this question and I am not getting a clear answer.

I understand that the emulators do not support Bluetooth. I also know of various guides explaining the functions, classes, and such, and I know people have mentioned that setting up a Bluetooth emulator is possible with Virtualbox. I even came across some old projects like BT-Sim that seemed like a way to create fake BT signals (though if my android emulator doesn't support BT, it doesn't help too much)

But no solid guide on how to get this going. It just likes a few scattered puzzle peaces that need to be stitched together. It makes me wonder how app developers reliably make BT enabled apps?

Are there any guides that dissect how to do this process? I imagine the steps to accomplish are:

1. Create a custom emulator on Virtualbox that can simulate Bluetooth?
2. Get the AVD Manager to talk to this emulator so my compiled Android code will work with it
3. Run a Bluetooth simulator to send BT signals over a port in your computer

(I don't really know how to do either of those 3 though!)

My overall goal is as follows:

- Create an app that will collect data from a Bluetooth transmitter
- But first, create a simulator on my computer that can talk to my android emulator as if it were the real thing

I'll be honest, I do find it odd that the Google folks don't allow Bluetooth emulation on their AVD. I understand not allowing real telephone calls, but I don't see how Bluetooth can be abused like that.

Anyway, any help in setting up Bluetooth would be greatly appreciated and hopefully help many others out there!

NOTE: I am using the standard Eclipse + Android SDK setup with AVD to do my Android development. Planning to use API 10. However, if I need to use a different set up, I am fine. As long as it comes with a step by step guide! That would be very nice.

Comment: My first thought is if you have thought about acquiring a real device ? :-)

Comment: I have... but I mean I'd like to do my development on my computer before. It sound to me like using your actual real devise would be cumbersome. Every change in code you make, you have to re-upload, etc... Doesn't seem like the most efficient way to go.

Comment: Take same amount of time to deploy to real device as a emulator, maybe even less time. I have programmed android apps on and off for 2 years, used real device all the way because emulator is too slow to start up.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't realize it was that straight forward. I will play with that later today with my phone! I still have a Droid2, so i am limited to API8/v2.2 but that should be good enough

Comment: Well, I was able to connect my phone via ADB for about a minute before it barfed on me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12417148/adb-extremely-fickle-for-droid2-v2-3-4-on-windows-7-64bit

Comment: Wow I got to say, working with your actual phone is WAY cooler than the emulator!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but it's still unanswered. If you have a physical device, that seems easiest way to go. If, like me, you don't have a device it's still possible to develop with bluetooth and android. 
Download an [android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) iso, load it into virtualbox with bridged network setting and install it.
Plug in your bluetooth dongle and select the device from the 'usb' menu, alternatively you can set a device filter in the vm's settings page.
Now just use adb and connect to it, you can find the ip by going to console (alt+f1) and typing netcfg or ifconfig eth0. You may also need to type adbd on the android console - I do, but I don't see many people mention it so seems it's not always needed.

It still works with eclipse, and is much faster than the emulator. Even when I'm not doing bluetooth dev I use the vm rather than the emulator.