# Android ADB Not connecting to Droid 2

Tags: android, adb, android-2.2-froyo, motorola-droid

I am finding ADB extremely fuckle for my Droid 2. My computer is Windows 7 64bit and my Droid2 version is 2.3.4.

I have googled and searched Stack Overflow and found many people have a similar problem. But mine is a weird twist on it.

I can in fact connect my phone to my computer after a fresh install of ADB, however after I connect and run an app on it, the ADB connection dies and I cannot get it back.

I have tried the following:

1. Reinstalling the Android USB driver, editing the .INI file to match my hardware ID
2. Updating AVD to the latest addition. Same with SDK on Eclipse

   - This did work at first, but the connection died after running 1 app
3. Restarted my computer
4. `adb kill-server` and tried to cycle through it that way
5. Forced shut down ADB through the task manager
6. put ADB on my system variables path
7. Switched all my USB ports and used 3 different USB cables, including the stock one and my Kindle one.
8. Installing the [Motorola Drivers](http://www.motorola.com/consumers/v/index.jsp?vgnextoid=bda09ec8009a0210VgnVCM1000008806b00aRCRD) (which I think does nothing. After I install it, my phone doesn't appear on my device manager.)

   - I relied on the ones from `android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`
9. Restarted my phone (which worked once, but not the second, third, or fourth time)
10. Made sure USB Dev mode was on (cycled that a few times too)

I am stumped. Here is the output of my logcat before ADB pooped on me:

> 09-13 17:34:39.709: D/UsbService(1469): WaitDevNodeClosedTimeout()
>   09-13 17:34:39.709: D/UsbService(1469): UsbEventHandler(), Received
>   event: usb_devnode_closed 09-13 17:34:39.709: D/UsbService(1469):
>   Current Usb State:USB In-Switch Wait DevNod Close State 09-13
>   17:34:39.709: D/UsbService(1469): ReadCurrentUsbMode() 09-13
>   17:34:39.709: D/UsbService(1469): Current Usb Mode: Motorola Phone
>   Tools : E/(): Device disconnected

After this, it went completely dark, even after many reinstalling of the drivers, restarts, etc.

I have also tried to set up my ADB to connect to my phone over wifi, but it appears you need root access on your phone (as su or sudo does not work on the terminal emulator) and it also appears you have to go through a very risky flash to get that done. At least, that is what I read.

But, if there is a way to do this ADB connection over wifi without having to do a risky super-user hack, that would circumvent this fiasco too!

I suppose this is a 2.5 part question -- How to make the ADB connection stable or how to get ADB to work over wifi without needing Super user/root (or how to get Super user access without risking your phones life!)

Comment: Just got it working by switching USB mode to "USB Mass Storage" and not "PC Mode" however... we'll see how long this lasts...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think I solved it. Basically, when you plug the phone into the computer, make sure it is in USB Mass Storage mode! Now, its been working consistently all night. So I think I got it.